How to display label above a multiple select listbox?
I have two multiple select boxes with some javascript to move the items between the boxes. I want to add a label to the boxes that displays above each of the listboxes but cant get the CSS to work.
Below is what the UI looks like with the boxes added without the label added to the element:

And below here is what the image looks like with the label added:

Code that I'm currently using to generate the image with the label added is below:


.addprop-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.addprop-container label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.listbox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.buttons button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="addprop-container">
  <label for="listbox1">Available Properties:</Label>
  <select name="all-properties" id="listbox1" class="listbox" multiple>
    <option value="1001">Test Line 1</option>
    <option value="1002">Test Line 2</option>
    <option value="1003">Test Line 3</option>
    <option value="1004">Test Line 4</option>
    <option value="1005">Test Line 5</option>
    <option value="1006">Test Line 6</option>
    <option value="1007">Test Line 7</option>
    <option value="1008">Test Line 8</option>
  </select>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> >> </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> > </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> < </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> << </button>
  </div>
  <label for="listbox2">Assigned to User:</Label>
  <select name="assigned-properties[]" id="listbox2" class="listbox" multiple>
  </select>
</div>




You need one more wrapper and then stack the label and select in that container


.addprop-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.select-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  /* Stack label and select vertically */
  align-items: flex-start; /* Align items to the start */
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.listbox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.buttons button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="addprop-container">
  <div class="select-group">
    <label for="listbox1">Available Properties:</label>
    <select name="all-properties" id="listbox1" class="listbox" multiple>
      <option value="1001">Test Line 1</option>
      <option value="1002">Test Line 2</option>
      <option value="1003">Test Line 3</option>
      <option value="1004">Test Line 4</option>
      <option value="1005">Test Line 5</option>
      <option value="1006">Test Line 6</option>
      <option value="1007">Test Line 7</option>
      <option value="1008">Test Line 8</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> >> </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> > </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> &lt; </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> &lt;&lt; </button>
  </div>

  <div class="select-group">
    <label for="listbox2">Assigned to User:</label>
    <select name="assigned-properties[]" id="listbox2" class="listbox" multiple>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>




My approach would be as follows, though I've largely rewritten much of the example you posted; the comments in the code explain the changes I've made:


console.clear()

// I don't like typing 'document' repeatedly, so it's stored as
// a variable under D:
const D = document,
  // creating an Array of buttons using the rest operator/statement
  // to convert the results of document.querySelectorAll() from a
  // NodeList in order to allow Array methods to be used:
  buttons = [...D.querySelectorAll(".buttons button")],
  boxes = [...D.querySelectorAll("select")]

// an Object of functions:
const move = {
  // both of these functions ('all' and 'selected') are
  // nearly identical, but I left them as separate functions
  // in the event you choose/need to add/remove functionality
  // in future:
  all(evt) {
    // destructuring assignment to retrieve the evt.target
    // property as a new variable also named 'target':
    let {
      target
    } = evt,
    // using document.querySelector to retrieve an element
    // via the id that's stored in the <button> element's
    // data-to custom attribute:
    recipient = D.querySelector(`#${target.dataset.to}`),
      // and here we retrieve the <select> element within the
      // document that does not have the id stored in the
      // <button> element's data-to custom attribute (there's
      // almost certainly better ways to get these two
      // elements):
      source = D.querySelector(`select:not(#${target.dataset.to})`)

    // as this is the all() function - move.all() - we're appending
    // all the children of the source element:
    recipient.append(...source.children)
    // we then call the sortChildren function held in the same
    // Object as this function in order to sort them within
    // their parent:
    this.sortChildren(recipient)
  },
  selected(evt) {
    let {
      target
    } = evt,
    recipient = D.querySelector(`#${target.dataset.to}`),
      source = D.querySelector(`select:not(#${target.dataset.to})`)

    // this is the only difference from the all() function,
    // rather than appending all children to the recipient
    // element, here we look within the source element and
    // select only its ':checked' children (the selected
    // <option> elements), and append those:
    recipient.append(...source.querySelectorAll(":checked"))
    this.sortChildren(recipient)
  },
  sortChildren(parent) {
    // a simple function that appends the sorted children of itself to
    // itself:
    parent
      .append(
        // using spread to have the append function work with individual
        // nodes of the Array rather than having it append the Array
        // itself:
        ...[
          // using the spread operator again to convert the iterable
          // NodeList of the parent to an Array, so that we can use
          // Array.prototype.sort():
          ...parent.children
        ].sort(
          // here we use Array.prototype.sort() to compare each element
          // against the Array's next entry, these are all <option> elements
          // and have a value attribute and property, here we do a simple
          // comparison of the values and place the smaller value on the left
          // and the greater value on the right. Because JavaScript uses
          // lexical sorting by default (2 is greater than 1, but also
          // 'greater' than 10, 100, 1000...) I use parseFloat() - in case
          // you wish to use floats in your <option> values - to convert
          // the text of the attribute (attributes are always strings) into
          // a number:
          (a, b) => parseFloat(a.value) > parseFloat(b.value)
        ));
    // returning the parent's children NodeList (as an Array) to the
    // calling context (just in case it's ever wanted):
    return [...parent.children];
  },
}

// iterating over the <button> elements:
buttons.forEach((btn) =>
  // and adding an event listener to respond to the 'click' event,
  // this takes the current btn (<option> element) and uses its custom
  // data-move attribute to determine which function of the move Object
  // to use, and passes in the evt reference:
  btn.addEventListener("click", (evt) => move[btn.dataset.move](evt)),
)
/* setting the <body> as a container: */

body {
  container: page / inline-size;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.addprop-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  /* defining named grid-columns of various sizes: */
  grid-template-columns: [all-start one-start] minmax(10rem, 2fr) [one-end buttons-start] minmax( 5rem, 1fr) [buttons-end two-start] minmax(10rem, 2fr) [two-end all-end];
  /* setting the inline size to be 75%, or 20rem at minimum, or 1000px at the maximum: */
  inline-size: clamp(20rem, 75%, 1000px);
  /* using auto on the inline margins to center the element on the inline axis
     (left/right in English) */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* nesting the container query, which takes effect when the container's
     width is less than 30rem (using the newer range syntax): */
  @container page (width < 30rem) {
    /* here we style the element selected by the current selector for the
       CSS ruleset we're nested within, sort of like using 'this' in JavaScript: */
    & {
      /* we redefine the columns of the element to have only one column taking all
         available space: */
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      /* more nesting, setting the flex-direction, and flex-wrap, of the
           .buttons element(s) to row (direction) and wrap if needed: */
      .buttons {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        /* this is probably crying out for an Xzibit joke, but yet more nesting;
               this time to set flex: 1 (flex-grow: 1) on the <button> elements since
               at this point - within the smaller page layout - they should probably
               take as much room as they can get, but adjust to your taste: */
        button {
          flex: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

label {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

select,
option {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

select {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* 1lh is equivalent to the line-height of the current element: */
  min-block-size: 10lh;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: 0.5em;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="addprop-container">
  <!-- I chose to wrap the <select> elements within
       the <label> elements to more easily align them;
       this also makes the 'for' attribute more or less
       unnecessary though I left it alone in case you
       were using it elsewhere: -->
  <label for="listbox1">Available Properties
    <select name="all-properties" id="listbox1" class="listbox" multiple>
      <option value="1001">Test Line 1</option>
      <option value="1002">Test Line 2</option>
      <option value="1003">Test Line 3</option>
      <option value="1004">Test Line 4</option>
      <option value="1005">Test Line 5</option>
      <option value="1006">Test Line 6</option>
      <option value="1007">Test Line 7</option>
      <option value="1008">Test Line 8</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div class="buttons">
    <!-- I changed the text of your button elements
         to HTML entities (this may be a personal thing
         now, but historically the use of 'naked' < characters
         could cause problems with the browser engine/parser);
         the first became &raquo, which looks similar to
         the original '>>' but isn't the same; to illustrate
         this the '<<' button uses '&laquo;' twice which
         you may prefer (or you could simply use your original
         text of course -->
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" data-move="all" data-to="listbox2">
      &raquo;
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" data-move="selected" data-to="listbox2">
      &gt;
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" data-move="selected" data-to="listbox1">
      &lt;
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" data-move="all" data-to="listbox1">
      &lt;&lt;
    </button>
  </div>
  <label for="listbox2">Assigned to User:
    <select
      name="assigned-properties[]"
      id="listbox2"
      class="listbox"
      multiple
    ></select>
  </label>
</div>



JS Fiddle demo.
References:

CSS:

container.
display.
flex.
flex-flow.
font-family.
font-size.
gap.
grid-template-columns.
inline-size.
justify-content.
margin.
margin-inline.
min-block-size.
padding.


JavaScript:

Array.prototype.filter().
Array.prototype.forEach().
Array.prototype.from().
Array.prototype.sort().
destructuring assignment.
document.
document.querySelector().
document.querySelectorAll().
Element.append().
Element.children().
Event.
EventTarget.
EventTarget.addEventListener().
parseFloat().
Template literals (template strings).




I am not sure if i understood your question clearly but based on the provided image and the question i think this is what you wanted to achieve right?


#available_prop_container,
#assigned_prop_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.addprop-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.addprop-container label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.listbox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.buttons button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="addprop-container">
  <div id="available_prop_container">
    <label for="listbox1">Available Properties:</Label>
    <select name="all-properties" id="listbox1" class="listbox" multiple>
      <option value="1001">Test Line 1</option>
      <option value="1002">Test Line 2</option>
      <option value="1003">Test Line 3</option>
      <option value="1004">Test Line 4</option>
      <option value="1005">Test Line 5</option>
      <option value="1006">Test Line 6</option>
      <option value="1007">Test Line 7</option>
      <option value="1008">Test Line 8</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> >> </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox1,listbox2)"> > </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> < </button>
    <button type="button" class="prop-selection" onclick="moveAllOptions(listbox2,listbox1)"> << </button>
  </div>
  <div id="assigned_prop_container">
    <label for="listbox2">Assigned to User:</Label>
    <select name="assigned-properties[]" id="listbox2" class="listbox" multiple>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>



